# Finding Substring in HIVE

Tags: hive, impala

I am trying to get substring values from a String(composite_key):
My composite_key looks like as mentioned below:

```
string1|string2|string3|string4|string5|string6|string7
```

I am able to find string1, string2,string3,string4 and string5 using substring method of impala

Can someone please help me finding String6 and String7 using substring method?

Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: please post some example code of what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using below queries:

For String7

```
select substring(composite_key,locate('|',composite_key,locate('|',composite_key,locate('|',composite_key,locate('|',composite_key,locate('|',composite_key, locate('|',composite_key) + 1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)as a
```

For String6

```
select
substring(composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key, 
locate('|',composite_key) + 1)+1)+1)+1)+1, 
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key, 
locate('|',composite_key) + 1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
- locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key,
locate('|',composite_key, 
locate('|',composite_key) + 1)+1)+1)+1)-1) 
as a
```

Answer (score 1):

You have use Hive subquery + array data structure + split function to accomplish this. However, this only works in Hive. The Impala does not support nested data structure yet, except for parquet based table in Impala 2.3 (corresponding to CDH 5.5) and higher.

```
select 
key_array[0] part0,
key_array[1] part1, 
key_array[2] part2, 
key_array[3] part3, 
key_array[4] part4, 
key_array[5] part5, 
key_array[6] part6, 
from (
select split(composite_key,'|') as key_array 
from mytable
) as temp
```